# WP_Query get post by category id returns all categorries

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a `WP_Query` that retrieves all posts in a certain category and display the posts on a blog page.

```
<?php
    $args  = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cat' => 24,
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $query->have_posts() ):
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'templates/content/content', 'loop' );
    endwhile;
?>
```

Although the query returns only published posts in descending order, the category parameter is ignored (it returns the content loop template for all categories instead of just category 24).

This is the category URL from the admin panel: `http://www.apokalipsa.si/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=24&post_type=post&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dcategory`

I tried swapping the `'cat' => 24,` query param with `'tag_ID' => 24,` (from the category URL in the categories page) but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried with 'category' => 24 and  'post_type'  => 'post'? You can use WP function get_posts(['category' => 24]) as well.

Comment: Yeah, tried both `'category' => '24',` and `'category' => 24,`, does not work...How would you implement the get_post function into the while loop? Is that a function on the query results?

Comment: try category slug `'category_name' => 'your_cat_slug', // this is the category SLUG`

Comment: @ParthaviPatel this returns the category and all the other categories nested underneath it (but ignores the other categories, which is a step forward). Is there a way to only get the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $args  = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category__in' => 24,
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);


    while ($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();

        get_template_part('templates/content/content', 'loop');
    endwhile;
```

you can try this